# Why does my canvas only draw 1 of the shapes?

Tags: javascript

```
            {
              var selectEl = document.getElementById("shapes");
              var selectedIndex = selectEl.selectedIndex;
              var selectedShape = selectEl[selectedIndex].value; 
              
              var context = null;
              var canvasObj = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
              //check if canvas api is supported
              if (canvasObj.getContext)
                 context = canvasObj.getContext("2d");  
              else
                  alert("Canvas API not supported");  
              if(selectedShape === "square")
              {  
                //context.clearRect(0,0,canvasObj.width,canvasObj.height);
                for(var i = 0; i<20; i++)
                  changeBackgroundColor(canvasObj, context);
                  writeToCanvas(canvasObj, context); 
                  drawSquare(canvasObj,context); 
                
                  
              }
              else if(selectedShape === "circle") 
              {    
                 //context.clearRect(0,0,canvasObj.width,canvasObj.height); 
                 for(var i = 0; i<20; i++) 
                   changeBackgroundColor(canvasObj, context);  
                   writeToCanvas(canvasObj, context);
                   drawCircle(canvasObj,context); 
              } 
            }
```

Here is the code for my getShape function and stuff.

Now here is the code for my drawSquare function:

```
            {
              //if I want a random number between 0 and 50 random()*(max-min-1)+min
              var xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random()* theCanvas.width); //returns a number between 0 and just under 1
              //alert(xCoord); 
              var yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random()* theCanvas.height);
              //alert(yCoord);
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
              ctx.fillRect(xCoord,yCoord,10,10);
              ctx.stroke();
            }
```

Anyone here know why my canvas only draws 1 of its shape? I have for a loop. It worked before, but now it doesn't.

Comment: For functions, please include the `function <name>()` line directly in your code. This will make your code more clear for us to help you.

Comment: With that said, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Because you used an else-if?

Comment: Else if doesn't affect it in this case. I tried changing it, still had the same problem.

Comment: So did you add console.log lines and verify the function is called many times? We also have no clue what the other methods do.....